# How to import angular library in reactjs?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

I am trying to use a style library from work for building an application for internal use. I am building the application with React, but the only one I can access is an AngularJs library starting with '@SomeStyle'. Is there any way to use the AngularJs library in React?

I tried simply use 'import' in react, the code compiles, but the browser respond with error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`.

I use babel loader, which transpile the 'import' syntax in my js file. The project runs, but it crashes when I import the angular style library.

The error comes from the code I imported from angular library, which is added to the bundle.js automatically (I think it is similar to C++ include). From my dev tool I see this line `import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'` cause an error.

Comment: That error means that your code is not transpiled properly. What is your configuration?

Comment: You are right, it is a error of import. The error comes from the code I imported from angular library. From my dev tool I see this line `import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'` cause an error.  I use babel loader, which transpile the 'import' syntax in my js file fine. The project runs, but it crashes when i import the angular style library.